# React Route is not working | element Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Nav from './components/nav';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.app'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
       <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/'>
                    <Nav></Nav>
                    <Home></Home> 
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The preview is not working. Didn't see any error. Why it is..? Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing `BrowseRoute` is inside index.js file.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

And Second is that

```
<Routes>
<Route path="/" element={<Component />} />
</Routes>
```